# Sendemail using json

Tags: php, json, email

I using a template but I am having trouble sending email using sendemail.php. I could not figure out the problem. Here are the codes

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Mesajınız Gönderildi!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
//$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'emailxxx@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

here is the html part of the codes

```
 <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="İsim">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Gönder</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Please help me :-)

Comment: Can you give the error you got?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. Actually it says "message sent successfully" but just doesn't send the email to the specified address.

Comment: can you remove the @ on @mail? Because the @ will ignore all notification error.

Comment: I did but still doesn't give eny error. Same succesfully sent message

Comment: Do you have the source of your template?

Comment: in the html , input codes don't have name="xxx" for the post? Am I right or it is OK

Comment: yes here is the address I downloaded from

Comment: https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524966-xeon-best-onepage-site-template

Comment: Try to remove all the @ on trim also. lets see what will happen

Comment: Nope, didn't work, no error :-(

Comment: Do you use it in public server? mail function will not work in Local server.

Comment: I uploaded it to the public server.

Comment: Is it working on a public server?

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: Do you get an error on the server?

Comment: I don't get any error. I fill the fields and hit send button then I get "your message was sent successfully" message but I don't have any message in the specified mail address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a mail library such as PHPMailer. Sendmail is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: this is not answer of OP's question.